# Add/import a style using REST

Tags: style, geoserver-rest-api

I have zipped a sld file and import it with

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/zip" --data-binary @C:/GIS/testdata/vk_al.zip http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/arbetsyta1/styles
```

The response is:

```
Default Styler
```

And a new style named Default Styler is created with the contents of the zipped sld.

With the name flag:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "name: vk_al" -H "Content-type: application/zip" --data-binary @C:/GIS/testdata/vk_al.zip http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/arbetsyta1/styles
```

I get the error:

```
<title>Error 403 Style Default Styler already exists.</title>
```

How do I name the style vk_al and not Default Styler?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue. Check your style files. In my case some styles did not contain the tag `<Name>` under `<UserStyle>`, thus they were give `Default Styler` during parsing rest api post request. Obviously, starting from the second one they were rejected due to name duplication.